# The system crash when go out from the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, methods, crash

I have this situation:
I want to go out from the activity after some second, but after that the system crash.
I insert these lines:

```
    static  QRActivity o;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /////other codes

    o =new QRActivity();

    public static void myMethod()
        {
            o.doStuff();
        }

        private  void doStuff()
        {
            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent i = new Intent(QRActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);

               }
            }, 5000);
        }

    in an other class
    QRActivity.myMethod();
```

It is working but after the seconds set going in crash and say
 real application class is null
No instant run dex files added to classpath
Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts

where is my mistake

Answer (score 0):

If `QRActivity` extends `Activity` then you absolutely positively may not do this:

```
o = new QRActivity();
```

Only the Android framework can create instances of an `Activity`. Your architecture is flawed.

Comment: Thanks David I done it but I continue to have always a crash.

Comment: Post your modified code and the stacktrace from logcat

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass extends Activity {

    static MyClass o;

    public static void myMethod()
    {
        o.doStuff();
    }

    private  void doStuff()
    {
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MyClass.this,MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                i.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        }, 5000);
    }
```

recall with 
MyClass.myMethod();

this the error:
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4168bc80)
//  real application class is null.
W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath